# How to Write Json Array to file using jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I created a Json file where i wanted to write write java object as Array element. Im using jackson.

```
    try{
           String json;
           String phyPath = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
           String filepath = phyPath + "resources/" + "data.json";
           File file = new File(filepath);
           if (!file.exists()) {
               System.out.println("pai nai");
               file.createNewFile();               
           }  
           json = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(story);
           Files.write(new File(filepath).toPath(), Arrays.asList(json), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);    
    }
```

This is not what i exactly want .it creates data like

```
{
  "storyTitle" : "ttt",
  "storyBody" : "tttt",
  "storyAuthor" : "tttt"
}
{
  "storyTitle" : "a",
  "storyBody" : "a",
  "storyAuthor" : "a"
}
```

I just need to create a Array of Json where i add java object, data should be like this

```
[{
  "storyTitle" : "ttt",
  "storyBody" : "tttt",
  "storyAuthor" : "tttt"
}
,{
  "storyTitle" : "a",
  "storyBody" : "a",
  "storyAuthor" : "a"
}]
```

Comment: unrelated tip: it is not necessary to create the file if it does not exist. Just write to it.

Comment: `writeValueAsString(story);` can you show code which defines what `story` is?

Comment: I got the write way i have write it as Array

Answer (score 34):

Jackson provide inbuilt methods for writing JSON data to JSON file.
    you can use these sort of code line for this

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer(new DefaultPrettyPrinter());
writer.writeValue(new File("D:/cp/dataTwo.json"), jsonDataObject);
//new file(path of your file)
```

and `jsonDataObject` is your actual object(i.e object or array) which you want to write in file.

Comment: I tried this its override previous data every time i created new data.I need add data as a elemen of Json array.

Comment: anyidea how to publish the amount of written value using jackson?

Comment: can we get an api with some sane defaults i can actually remember:

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.writeFile("/my/path", object)

Answer (score 7):

It can be done by using arrays:

```
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    Student student = new Student();

    student.setActive(false);
    student.setFirstName("Kir");
    student.setId(123);
    student.setLastName("Ch");

    objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

    try {
        List<Student> listOfStudents = new ArrayList<>();
        listOfStudents.add(student);
        listOfStudents.add(student);
        objectMapper.writeValue(new File("d:/temp/output.json"), listOfStudents);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The result will be like this:

```
[ {
  "id" : 123,
  "firstName" : "Kir",
  "lastName" : "Ch",
  "active" : false,
  "address" : null,
  "languages" : null
}, {
  "id" : 123,
  "firstName" : "Kir",
  "lastName" : "Ch",
  "active" : false,
  "address" : null,
  "languages" : null
} ]
```